Orange warning message appears when running Streamlit AI chatbot in MS Teams
I developed a Python AI web chatbot based on Streamlit on an Azure VM, and I registered our company’s domain and SSL certificate to launch the service. While everything works fine in a web browser, an orange warning message appears at the top of the screen when I register and run the app in MS Teams. The content of the warning is not visible, which negatively affects the user experience.
enter image description here

Python Code

enter image description here

Manifest.json code for uploading Teams APP

enter image description here
"I checked the console through the developer tools, and I keep seeing the appInitTimeout error message. I believe this is related to the SDK initialization timing out. I tried to resolve the issue by adding the Teams JavaScript API code according to the MS guide, but the warning still persists."
text
enter image description here

While the screenshot of the error is necessary (if a bit big...), please do not add screenshots of code, but instead [edit] your post and copy-paste the code directly into the text.

please provide the code as text not screenshots
